# Two rows of a table with different number of cells, but equal width?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I am trying to make a table with two rows. Each row has a different number of cells. Each cell on both rows should be equal in width, and each row should be equal width as well. Hopefully I've explained that correctly.
Here is what I've done so far: -

HTML: -

```
<table class="top-table">
  <tr>
    <td width="14%">2007-2016</td>
    <td width="14%">2017</td>
    <td width="14%">2018</td>
    <td width="14%">2019</td>
    <td width="14%">2020</td>
    <td width="14%">2021</td>
    <td width="14%">2022</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  
<table class="bottom-table">
  <tr>
    <td width="11%">Event 1</td>
    <td width="11%">Event 2</td>
    <td width="11%">Event 3</td>
    <td width="11%">Event 4</td>
    <td width="11%">Event 5</td>
    <td width="11%">Event 6</td>
    <td width="11%">Event 7</td>
    <td width="11%">Event 8</td>
    <td width="11%">Event 9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS: -

```
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: blue;
}

.top-table {
  width: 100%;
}

.bottom-table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

I've tried doing it with one table, but couldn't figure it out, which is why I made two separate tables instead. Surely there should be something easier? The nearest I could find it [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9yrM/1/), but that's using divs.

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: blue;
}

.top-table {
  width: 100%;
}

.bottom-table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="top-table">
  <tr>
    <td width="14%">2007-2016</td>
    <td width="14%">2017</td>
    <td width="14%">2018</td>
    <td width="14%">2019</td>
    <td width="14%">2020</td>
    <td width="14%">2021</td>
    <td width="14%">2022</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="bottom-table">
  <tr>
    <td width="11%">Event 1</td>
    <td width="11%">Event 2</td>
    <td width="11%">Event 3</td>
    <td width="11%">Event 4</td>
    <td width="11%">Event 5</td>
    <td width="11%">Event 6</td>
    <td width="11%">Event 7</td>
    <td width="11%">Event 8</td>
    <td width="11%">Event 9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you describe why/how this is a table - it sounds more like a grid.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: blue;
}

.top-table {
  width: 100%;
}

.bottom-table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="top-table">
  <tr>
    <td width="14%">2007-2016</td>
    <td width="14%">2017</td>
    <td width="14%">2018</td>
    <td width="14%">2019</td>
    <td width="14%">2020</td>
    <td width="14%">2021</td>
    <td width="14%">2022</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="11%">Event 1</td>
    <td width="11%">Event 2</td>
    <td width="11%">Event 3</td>
    <td width="11%">Event 4</td>
    <td width="11%">Event 5</td>
    <td width="11%">Event 6</td>
    <td width="11%">Event 7</td>
    <td width="11%">Event 8</td>
    <td width="11%">Event 9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried that at first, but the top row doesn't increase to match the width of the bottom row.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do this with a table, by using the flexbox. It is important to insert the `<tbody>` because some browsers will insert it if it is missing. For the correct flex table the `<tbody>` is required.

Each row can have a different number of cells. By adjusting the percentage .td-7 (100% : 7) and .td-9 (100% : 9) you will get the correct width of the cells per row.

```css
.ftable, .ftable tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.ftable tbody, .ftable td {
  display: block;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.ftable td {
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: inherit;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}
tr.td-7 td {
  max-width: 14.285%;
}
tr.td-9 td {
  max-width: 11.111%;
}

/** example borders **/

.ftable {
  border-top: 1px solid silver;
  border-left: 1px solid silver;
}
.ftable td {
  border-right: 1px solid silver;
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
  font: normal 14px/1.3 sans-serif;
  padding: 2px 5px 4px 5px;
}
```

```html
<table class="ftable">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="top-table td-7">
      <td>2007-2016</td>
      <td>2017</td>
      <td>2018</td>
      <td>2019</td>
      <td>2020</td>
      <td>2021</td>
      <td>2022</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bottom-table td-9">
      <td>Event 1</td>
      <td>Event 2</td>
      <td>Event 3</td>
      <td>Event 4</td>
      <td>Event 5</td>
      <td>Event 6</td>
      <td>Event 7</td>
      <td>Event 8</td>
      <td>Event 9</td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think that's almost there. But if I add another "event cell" on the bottom row, the top row should increase to match the width of the bottom row.

Comment: Each row must have the same amount of cells (except the top row). If at the bottom row a event is added, then add a empty event cell on each other row.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out. This allows me to add an extra "event" cell, and that row will still span the above "date" row. The only thing is the size of the first date cell - I'm not sure why it's wider than the rest.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
}

th {
  background-color: #B3B3B3;
  border: 2px solid;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-date,
.nav-event {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<table class="nav-date">
  <tr>
    <th>2007-2016</th>
    <th>2017</th>
    <th>2018</th>
    <th>2019</th>
    <th>2020</th>
    <th>2021</th>
    <th>2022</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="nav-event">
  <tr>
    <td>Event 1</td>
    <td>Event 2</td>
    <td>Event 3</td>
    <td>Event 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```